# Passport CAS authentication strategy authentication failed error

Tags: node.js, passport.js, cas

I am building an application in NodeJS 12 Express 4. I am integrating the authentication with CAS using the [passport-cas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-cas) module.

Here is the configuration (example). Note I am using CAS2.0 but the instructions say to set the config to CAS3.0 and provide a validation endpoint, which I have done already.

```
# CAS 2.0 will work with the CAS 3.0 configuration, but you need to set the validation endpoint
CAS_VERSION=CAS3.0
CAS_SSO_BASE_URL=https://example-cas-server/cas
CAS_SERVER_BASE_URL=https://my-app.example.com/api/login/cas
CAS_VALIDATE_URL=https://example-cas-server/cas/serviceValidate
```

Configure the strategy

```
const passport = require('passport');
const CasStrategy = require('passport-cas').Strategy;

// Cas strategy passport.authenticate('cas');
passport.use(new CasStrategy({
  version: process.env.CAS_VERSION,
  ssoBaseURL: process.env.CAS_SSO_BASE_URL,
  serverBaseURL: process.env.CAS_SERVER_BASE_URL,
  validateURL: process.env.CAS_VALIDATE_URL
}, function (profile, done) {
  var login = profile.user;

  console.log(`****** CAS STRATEGY ******`);

  User.findOne({ login: login }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });

}));
```

Call the strategy and then callback after strategy is complete.

```
router.get('/api/login/cas', (req, res, next) => {

  passport.authenticate('cas', function (err, user, info) {
    // Callback after authentication strategy is complete

    console.log(`info: ${info}`);
    // Check error
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(404).json(err);
    }

    // Check if user was returned
    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    }
  })(req, res);
}

});
```

The authentication workflow appears to be working up to ticket validation. When the user logs in, the web app redirects to the SSO provider, the user enters the credentials in the SSO page, and then the response is sent back to the web app. However, it appears as though the validation process fails with this error message. The error occurs in the [passport-cas module source code index.js](https://github.com/sadne/passport-cas/blob/master/index.js#L106) lines 106 and 126.

The ST ticket is getting returned to the app as a query parameter `/api/login/cas?ticket=ST-1430649-Y-pvbZj5j5boKYi-tn4KQC684D8ip-10-137-43-111`. Although, I thought the ticket was supposed to be sent to the serviceValidate url for validation (not back to the app) before completing the strategy and calling the callback.

```
****** CAS STRATEGY ******
Error: Authentication failed
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/passport-cas/index.js:126:45
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:384:20)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at SAXParser.onclosetag (/home/node/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:348:26)
    at emit (/home/node/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:615:33)
    at emitNode (/home/node/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:620:3)
    at closeTag (/home/node/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:861:5)
    at SAXParser.write (/home/node/app/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1294:29)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/home/node/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:403:31)
    at Parser.parseString (/home/node/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:6:61)
    at exports.parseString (/home/node/app/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:433:19)
    at Strategy._validate (/home/node/app/node_modules/passport-cas/index.js:106:21)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/passport-cas/index.js:195:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1168:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
GET /api/login/cas?ticket=ST-1430649-Y-pvbZj5j5boKYi-tn4KQC684D8ip-10-137-43-111 404 123.623 ms - 2
```

**Question:**

How should I proceed to troubleshoot the issue? As mentioned the SSO provider seems to be doing its job correctly and returning the ST ticket. There seems to be an issue with the ticket validation, but that is just a theory.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the passport-cas module parsing was causing the issue. The XML response I was getting back from the CAS 2.0 server did not seem to be in the same format as what the module was expecting in the response. I created my own custom passport strategy to solve this issue.